# Check input type of Custom View without getInputType

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view

My question is about Android/Java.

How can I check the input type of an custom view without creating an attr.xml?

My main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"/>

    <org.javaforum.input
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your E-Mail"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

My input.java:

```
public class input extends TextView{
    public input(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr, getIdentifier(attr));
    }
    
    public static int getIdentifier(AttributeSet attr){
        //How can check if input type are textEmailAddress?
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        
    }
}
```

So I wanna know if the inputtype of my custom view was set to "textEmailAddress". How can I do this? I can't use the method getInputType because in my case the object are not initialised yet. How can I solve my problem without the "getInputType" method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Input extends TextView {

    private static final int[] INPUT_TYPE_ATTR = new int[]{android.R.attr.inputType};

    public Input(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr, getIdentifier(context, attr));
    }

    public static int getIdentifier(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attr, INPUT_TYPE_ATTR);
        try {
            final int inputType = a.getInt(0, 0);
            if (inputType == (EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                    EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS)) {
                // your logic here
            }
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
    }
}
```

Comment: What?!? It really works!! I didn't understand that I must to compare TYPE_CLASS_TEXT with TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS. But now I have homework. I wanna look for more information about it.